# octopus-deploy *.ocl configuration files upload to another octopus server

Tags: octopus-deploy, octopus

Is there any way to discard ocl processes saved with the help of VCS enabled in Octopus project on Octopus Server 1 that has access to VCS and upload them directly to another Octopus, another Project, when that Octopus Server 2, has no access to VCS?

I've searched Octopus Project to find a menu that allows "Upload OCL" - none. Tried to search Octopus Server for a folder that will allow me to throw ocl files but they come with a hash generated, usually generated by VCS.
Is there some workaround for a task I try to accomplish? I need to move processes, and variables, variable sets without manually configuring them.